# How to calculate the differential of a local chart?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I've this problem. If I have a manifold $M$ of dimension $m$ and a local chart $\varphi:M\rightarrow \varphi(M)$ which is the matrix that represents the differential of this application? Thanks in advice for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A local chart is a diffeomorphism between an open subset of $M$ and an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$. This implies that the differential $d\phi_x : T_x M \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is an isomorphism for any $x$ in the domain of $\phi$. Consequently, we can define a basis $\mathcal{B} = \{b_1,\dots,b_m\}$ of $T_x M$ by setting $b_i = d\phi_x^{-1}(e_i)$, where $\mathcal{E} = \{e_1,\dots,e_m\}$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^m$. The matrix representing $d\phi_x$ with respect to $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{E}$ is then simply the identity matrix.

Comment: It was my opinion too, but I wasn't sure. You've been very helpful... sorry for my bad English!